# Should I use currying with HOCs in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it less performant or bad practice to do currying? Is it better performance or better practice? Or is it all just preference. I can't really find any concrete evidence on the subject.

```
class MyClass extends React.component {
 ...
}
export default HOC(someParam)(MyClass)
```

Vs:

```
class MyClass extends React.component {
 ...
}
export default HOC(someParam, MyClass)
```

---

Example HOC (currying):

```js
export default function HOC(someParam){
 // do something with someParam here
 return function(ChildComponent){
   return (props) => ( <ChildComponent {...props}/> )
 }
}
```

Example HOC (not currying):

```
export default function HOC(someParam, childComponent){
 // do something with someParam here
 return (props) => ( <ChildComponent {...props}/> )
}
```

Comment: It's all up to you.  React is js.  It's ok to curry in JS.  Go for it if it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, any difference is going to be so negligible as to be irrelevant. Creating functions takes nanoseconds, and you're only going to do it once per class anyway.

So the decision should come down to whether you get a benefit out of doing so. If you use lots of higher order components, you may find it useful to use composition to combine multiple HOCs together. And if that's the case the currying will be very useful, since composition typically requires functions to be unary. For example:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
  // whatever
}


export default compose(
  withI18n,
  withTheme,
  connect(state => ({ foo: state.foo }),
  HOC("someValue") // <-- this would be from your curried example
)(MyClass)

// Without composition, this would be the following... i think.
withI18n(withTheme(connect(state => ({ foo: state.foo }))(HOC("someValue", MyClass))));
```